# Собачее/собачье слово

Tags: орфография

Можно ли предложение 2-е вместо 1-го использовать?

> «Гав» — это собачье слово.

> «Гав» — это собачее слово.

Почему прилагательные *собачий* и *кошачий* черезмягкозначно склоняются, но, например, *висячий* (тоже есть ***ч***) — по-нормальному (*висячее ухо*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: *«Гав» — это **собачье** слово.*

**РАЗДЕЛИТЕЛЬНЫЙ МЯГКИЙ ЗНАК В ПРИТЯЖАТЕЛЬНЫХ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫХ**

(1) Нужно **различать** притяжательные и качественные прилагательные

Разделительный мягкий знак пишется в косвенных падежах и форме мн.числа **притяжательных** прилагательных с суффиксом ИЙ: ***птичий – птичьи, птичьего.***

Но их надо **отличать** от сходных **качественных** прилагательных, в которых **нет разделительного** мягкого знака: ***горячий – горячие, горячего.***

(2) Для понимания данной орфограммы следует разобрать прилагательные **по составу:**

**качественное прилагательное**: горячИЙ – **окончание ИЙ;** горячЕГО – окончание ЕГО,

**притяжательное прилагательное:** птичий – нулевое окончание, **суффикс ИЙ**; птичьЕГО – разделительный Ь перед окончание ЕГО, звук Й относится к суффиксу ***ИЙ***, где ***И*** – беглая.

**Примеры**

Мне душно от **жгучего** света.

Небо молнией **летучей** опоясалось кругом.

Сырая даль от **птичьих** стай чернела.

Они вошли в село, встреченные **собачьим** лаем.